# Is it possible to invoke different overloads of dereference operator depending on the type of range-based for

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm pretty sure that it is impossible but just to get a certainty - is it possible to invoke different unary operator* "overloads"(?) on the iterator of the collection depending on used type in a ranged based for. I'm especially interested in invoking two different overloads for:

```
for (auto &e: collection)
```

and

```
for (auto e: collection)
```

But the question can be more generalized for given type of `e`.

Comment: 'Is it possible...' -> have you tried that? Did it work? If no, what isn't working as expected?

Comment: How are the operators overloaded?

Comment: @ForceBru As I said - I'm pretty sure that it is impossible cause I don't even know what syntax would it involve... The question raised while implementing a `trie` collection for my purpose...

Comment: The question doesn't make sense since ranged-based fors don't give you direct access to the iterator.

Comment: @user6292850: If range-based for gave access to the iterator, the question would be pointless. He could invoke whatever method he wants on it then.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The question says "different unary operator* "overloads"(?) on the iterator of the collection". Or am I not reading that correctly?

Comment: Chosen overload doesn't depend of expected return type.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I believe that would be the key here to state that this is impossible...

Comment: You could simply avoid `auto` here and use an explicit wrapper object to call the correct overload.

Comment: @user6292850: Yes, that's what it says. If he could access the iterator, he wouldn't need help with this. There would be no problem to solve. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes probably it's the best way but the approach proposed by Maxim is also quite extensive. Thanks for tips!

Comment: Can you describe a use case, as well as the technique you are trying to use to solve it?

Comment: @Yakk Well, I use a suffix tree structure to remove all the subpaths of a specific kind of graphs. I created an iterator to access each of the subpaths, but the subpaths are intended to be created on the flight, yet sometimes I would like to access the subpath by a reference... This is the origins of my problem... :)

Comment: I think it is possible. Arrange for the `operator*` call to return a special type which will then have suitable conversion operators. A conversion to a reference-type could then call a suitable method to 'dereference'. Think of it as a lazy-dereference - delaying the call until the relevant type is known

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Very clever idea. I'll try to implement it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware that it is possible.

But you can get similar behaviour by iterating over different proxy objects:

```
for (auto &&e: collection.method1())
// ...
for (auto &&e: collection.method2())
```

The proxy objects returned by `method1` and `method2` implement `begin` and `end` function that return different types of iterators, which implement `operator*` differently.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg, well. An adapter class over a standard container may be possible. `method1(std_container)`. And will in fact extend to any "stl"-like object, such as the boost containers.

Comment: @StoryTeller There is interesting article [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197): _If you're writing a function that can be implemented as either a member or as a non-friend non-member, you should prefer to implement it as a non-member function. That decision increases class encapsulation. When you think encapsulation, you should think non-member functions._